# DAX sum over a measure?

Tags: dax

I have a DAX measure called Yearly_Leavers_Result which outputs certain values depending on the user's pivot table query. These are values like "Left", "Joined", "Remained". This has to be dynamically defined by the user so it has to be a measure. However, this only outputs the results in the pivot table row by row, and I need it to be aggregated by another field, Hours. So I need to have a breakdown of the categories "Left" "Joined" "Remained" in the pivot table, and the total Hours for each category.

I have tried the following:

```
    YearlyResultCategories = 
        SUMX(
            VALUES('TableName'[Yearly_Leavers_Result]), 
            CALCULATE(SUM('TableName'[Hours]))
            )
```

However, it gives an error, that a measure can't be used in a Values function.

Is there a way to sum over values produced by a measure? Thanks for your time.

Edit: this is the current pivot result:

| ID   | Yearly_Leavers_Result (measure) | Hours (column in values)|

| :----| :-------------------------------|:------------------------|

| 123  | Left                            | 1                       |

| 234  | Left                            | 0.5                     |

| 456  | Joined                          | 2                       |

| 678  | Joined                          | 1                       |

This is the desired pivot result:

| YearlyLeaversResultCategories | Hours (column in values)|

| ------------------------------|-------------------------|

| Left                          | 1.5                     |

| Joined                        | 3                       |

Comment: Sample data with expected result always helps.

Comment: @JosWoolley I've added current pivot and desired pivot reslts above, apologies for the formatting I couldn't get to work